# get count of a specific file in several directories

Tags: command-line, file-search

I have a directory structure as follows:

```
dir
   |___sub_dir1
              |_____files_1
   |___sub_dir2
              |_____files_2
   |___sub_dirN
              |_____files_N
```

Each sub_directory may or may not have a file called `xyz.json`. I want to find the total count of `xyz.json` files in the directory `dir`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use :

```
find path_to_dir -name xyz.json | wc -l
```

Comment: This works great for the example.  Here is a modified version of the same solution that you'll find performs better when searching many directories with many files. I further restrict find to only files, make it print a '.' for each one, then have wc count the dots, rather than lines.  It's a weird trick but it performs slightly better: `find path_to_dir -type f -name xyz.json -printf '.' | wc -c`

Answer (score 3):

An alternative using  shell globing

```
## Make ** match all files and 0 or more dirs and subdirs
$ shopt -s globstar

$ ls -dq **/xyz.json | wc -l
```